# Android incoming outgoing call recording

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-mediarecorder

I am using below code to record incoming and outgoing call conversation in android phone but
        this code only works when the mic or speaker is on and user disable speaker phone my code will not be able to record incoming outgoing call.
    I want to record incoming and outgoing call conversation without activating speaker of phone.

```
    class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener implements SensorEventListener {
            Context context;
            AudioManager audioManager;
            MediaRecorder recorder;
            private SensorManager mSensorManager;
            private Sensor myLightSensor;
            private boolean CallState;
            private float sensorState;

            public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                myLightSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
                audioManager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                if (myLightSensor == null){
                    Log.i("On Receive", "Not Support");
                }else{
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,myLightSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                }
            }

            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    System.out.println("My Call IDLE");
                    CallState = false;
                    StartAudioSpeacker();
                    StopRecording();
                    System.out.println("Is phone speaker : "+ audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn());
                    if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
                        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    System.out.println("My Call OFFHOOK");
                    CallState = true;
                    StartAudioSpeacker();
                    StartRecording();
                    System.out.println("Is phone speaker : "+ audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn());
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    System.out.println("My Call RINGING");
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
                    Log.i("Sensor Changed", "Accuracy :" + accuracy);
                }
            }

            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
                    Log.i("Sensor Changed", "onSensor Change :" + event.values[0]);
                    sensorState = event.values[0];
                    StartAudioSpeacker();
                }
            }

            public void StartAudioSpeacker(){
                if (CallState && sensorState == 1.0) {
                    audioManager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL), 1);
                    System.out.println("Is phone speaker : "+ audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn());
                }else{
                    audioManager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL), 1);
                    System.out.println("Speaker Volume :"+ audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL));
                    System.out.println("Is phone speaker : "+ audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn());
                }
            }
            public void StartRecording(){
                 recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                 recorder.setOutputFile(this.getFullSdPath());
                 try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Start Recording");
            }

            public void StopRecording(){
                 recorder.stop();
                 recorder.reset();   
                 recorder.release();
                 Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Stop Recording");
            }

            public String getFullSdPath(){
                File sdCard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()    + "/RecordMyVoice");
                if (!sdCard.exists()) {
                    sdCard.mkdir();
                }
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/RecordMyVoice/",new Date().getTime()+".3gp");
                System.out.println("Full path of record sound is : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to record incomming and outgoing call conversation without activating speaker of phone.

Sorry, but this is not supported in general on Android.